# Script not working on page load, but working from console

Tags: javascript, console, referrer

I wrote a script that's running from ebay listing iframe. It's working fine, it runs on $(document).ready(), sends an AJAX request to a remote server, gets some info, manipulate the DOM on 'success' callback, everything working perfect...

However, I added a piece of code, which should get the document.referrer, and extract some keywords from it, if they exist. Specifically, if a user searches ebay for a product, and clicks on my product from the results, the function extracts the keywords he entered.

Now, the problem is, that function is not running on page load at all. It seems like it blocks the script when it comes to that part. This is the function:

```
function getKeywords(){
    var index = window.parent.document.referrer.indexOf('_nkw');

    if (index >= 0){
        var currentIndex = index + 5;
        var keywords = '';
        while (window.parent.document.referrer[currentIndex] !== '&'){
            keywords += window.parent.document.referrer[currentIndex++];
        }
        keywords = keywords.split('+');

        return keywords;
    }
}
```

And I tried calling two logs right after it:

```
console.log('referrer: ' + window.parent.document.referrer);
console.log(getKeywords());
```

None of them is working. It's like when it comes to that 'window.parent.document.referrer' part, it stops completely.

But, when I put this all in a console, and run it, it works perfectly. It logs the right referrer, and the right keywords.

Does anybody know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Is the parent window in a different domain? That limits what you're allowed to access in it.

Comment: I don't think so. It's an ebay listing html, it should be served from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is working on the console is because your window object is the outer window reference and not your `iframe`. Besides that, on the console:

```
window.parent === window
  // ==> true
```

So, on in fact you are running `window.document.referrer` and not your frame's `window.parent.document.referrer`.

If you want to access your frame's window object you should something like

```
var myFrame = document.getElementsByClassName('my-frame-class')[0];
myFrame.contentWindow === window
  // ==> false
myFrame.contentWindow.parent.window === window
  // ==> true
```

This might help you debug your problem, but I guess the browser is just preventing an inner `iframe` from accessing the parent's window object.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand you. I want to access iframe's parent window. The iframe holds the html code for the listing template and my javascript code. But, I want to access the parent window, and it's refferrer.

Comment: The code you are running on the console has a different scope from the code running in an `iframe`, so you can execute somethings on the console that have different behaviour from the code running inside the `iframe`.